# Song of India(Dracaena Reflexa) getting yellow-brown leaves

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, watering, sunlight, dracaena

**Water Regime**: When the top soil feels dry to the touch. 1 litre of water every 7th day(cause they can do well with dry condition, right?).

**Placement & Light**: Sitting right against the Northern window. Bright indirect light for all day long. Fluorescent light for 3-4 hour after dusk.

**Soil**: Good, well-drained soil.

**Plant Condition**:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I removed a dead leaf(the one on the floor) 2-3 days back. Now there are some more leaves getting brown-yellow.

What's the case? Overwatering, or underwatering, or insufficient light, or too much light?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pot surface looks quite dry to me. While they are water efficient, these plants do need sufficient watering.

The death of lower leaves is not that concerning, under normal circumstances, because as the plant matures, it drops off lower leaves.

In this particular case, looks like 7 days is too much of a gap, especially if the soil is draining and potentially, there is a low humidity situation going on where the plant is situated.The drying, withering leaf tip is a good indicator that the plant is not getting enough water.

I grow this plant outdoors in Zone 9B, and they get water every 3rd day. The soil is draining, and mulched, and so far the plant is doing okay. For now, water the plant immediately, water every 3 or 4 days and see if the plant improves. Later on you can consider scaling back the schedule. Do not feed the plant fertilizers till it recovers, given it is currently distressed.

Comment: Perhaps a layer of mulch would help retain the moisture for longer? Doesn't appear to be any on top of the soil. Otherwise I agree with your answer :)

Comment: Yes, mulch would do a good job of retaining moisture. I mulch all my plants.